# Call a class in Visual studio through a button

Tags: c#

i have this project in my visual studio and i have a form which is linked to a solution in a project.

So, i need to call it on a button click.
It's like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             poComp.Client.StartpoComp  
        }
```

The thing is i have not copied the code the right way, houw should it proceed?
What is the file's structure?
Sorry, i know this might sound dumb and it probably is but i'm right in the beginning.

Comment: What is `poComp.Client.StartpoComp`? if its a method, just add `()` to the end. But please, don't use copy and paste as the first thing you do, it causes mistakes and you don't learn as much - Also, Why isn't this working? any errors?

Comment: it's a class, so is this correct? should i just add () at the end?

Comment: I don't know what your trying to do with it, you can do `new ..StartpoComp()` but then you would be better assigning this to a variable to use it

Comment: But then you want to create an instance of the class? If so then you need to assign the instance to something like:
StartpoComp  startpoComp  = new poComp.Client.StartpoComp();

Comment: help me please, so i need to click on this button and then i need to show the content of a string in the form, how should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below will do what (I think) you want to do but I strongly advise that you google "using classes c#" to try and find some tutorials

[Here is just one](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/introduction/)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartpoComp spc = new poComp.Client.StartpoComp();
    //myFormsLabel.Text = spc.SomePublicVariable;
    //spc.SomePublicMethod(param1);
}
```